# SQL CREATE TABLE permission denied for User but EXECUTE AS LOGIN works

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

One of our developers is trying to create a table in one of our databases. He's sent me a screenshot where I can see he's logged in with the user 'rem_test' and if he tries to create a Table he's getting the Error:

> CREATE TABLE permission denied on database "Test_DB"

Now when I try granting him the Permission with

`GRANT CREATE TABLE TO rem_test;`

I get

> Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

So I assume he seems to already have the permission. Just to make sure I've tested it with:

```
USE Test_DB;
EXECUTE AS LOGIN='rem_test';
create table dokument_custom_informationen (id integer not null, information varchar(max) null, value varchar(max) null);
REVERT;
```

And this works fine as the table is created. The User has db_datareader and db_datawriter Roles on the database.

What am I missing? Shouldn't these roles not include CREATE TABLE permissions? but why can I not Grant them then? Why does the EXECUTE AS work but when he tries to create the table it doesn't?

Thanks.

Comment: He's probably not logged in as that user

Comment: Get the developer to run `SELECT SYSTEM_USER AS LoginName, CURRENT_USER AS DatabaseUserName;` in the window that attempted to create the `TABLE` in; what does it return?

Comment: Side note, I would suggest that `MAX` is the wrong length option for those columns; are `information` and `value` *really* likely to contain values with more than 8,000 characters?

Comment: The query you've provided shows that he is indeed logged in as the "rem_test" user (both LoginName and DatabaseUserName). I've assigned the db_ddladmin Role to his user as a temporary solution. I'm aware of the Security issue, so I'm still searching for a better solution.

Comment: Maybe they're connected to the wrong database? What do they get for `select DB_NAME()`

Comment: This can't be the case either, as the permission error clearly states, that CREATE TABLE permissions are denied on "Test_DB" which is the database in question.